# Is it better have high cardinality of partition key?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

My understanding it's good to have high cardinality for choosing partition key. What I'm confused is how this impacts RUs. If you have cardinality partition key and you say issue update for specific value of partition key it would mean that all traffic will go into single partition and create "hot" partition and this will result in rate limiting per microsoft docs.

Answer (score 1):

Your partition key should be a value that is guaranteed to have as many different values as possible while you still have the ability to provide this value on every query. It should also be a value that is as evenly distributed between your documents as possible. You don't wanna have  5GB worth of documents in one partition thats begin hit all the time and then partitions withs 100 MB that barely get hit. This is because RUs are distributed evenly between your partitions no matter what and you will be wasting RUs or causing hot partitions (as you mentioned yourself.)

This is a bad distribution model for your partition values:

[image]

This is a good example:

[image]

Comment: So what happens if I choose value with high cardinality like second image and have to insert a bunch of values for specific value. That would mean all my writes will go to a single partition and I would not be able to get all my provisioned RUs?

Comment: You may indeed get 1/Nth of your provisioned RU/s in case of bad PK design (or bad luck). N being how many partition >ranges< (each containing M partitions) has been created for your partition keys internally.